# Can't approach a specific sheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I want to search for a specific sheet in my Excel file. I try to approach this sheet with:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.Worksheets[1];
```

But this doesn't work somehow, can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thanks in advance

```
public List<string> ExcelReader(string fileLocation, int sheetnummer)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = workBook.Worksheets[1]; // this doesn't work

    workBook.SaveAs(fileLocation + ".csv",
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
    workBook.Close(true);

    excel.Quit();

    List<string> valueList = null;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileLocation + ".csv"))
    {
        string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        valueList = new List<string>(
                    content.Split(
                        new string[] { "\r\n" },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
                    )
                );
    }

    new FileInfo(fileLocation + ".csv").Delete();

    return valueList;
}
```

Comment: how many sheets does your workbook have?

Comment: @derpirscher it does have 2 sheets at the moment

Comment: what's the error? "this doesnt work" is not a proper error description

Comment: And also explain your desired behaviour. In your current code, you assign `sheet`, but don't use it.

Comment: @derpirscher When I run the method, it (valueList) returns nothing

Comment: @derpirscher Can you explain me how to use the `sheet`? I thought this was the right way to go to my second sheet on in my excel file

Comment: What is the content of the first sheet? As far as I know save as cvs only handles the first sheet of the workbook

Comment: @derpirscher There are just a few numbers on the first sheet, I searched a method to read an excel file really fast, they said i had to use cvs

Comment: @derpirscher I want to read multiple sheets from the Excel file, so thats why I wanted to know how I could access another sheet, for exaple the second one

Comment: I don't think they meant "take an existing excel, convert it to cvs and parse the cvs". If you can control what file is generated in the beginning, create cvs. If you need to parse an exsting file, parse that file and take your values from there. See for instance this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel or use a third party lib like for instance epplus http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: @derpirscher Okay I guess thats the answer then :)